# JSXGraph: How to reduce the number of data points for drawing an arc

Tags: jsxgraph

If my understanding is correct, when I create an arc, the result is a curve with a data array to store the details for graphing. Please, correct me if this understanding is wrong.

I am trying to create a drawing that has a lot of arcs and I end up with a large SVG file. I would like to reduce the size of this file, but I do not mind a bit of quality loss on drawing the arcs.

My question is the following: Is there something that I can add when I create an arc that limits the size of the data array in the resulting curve? I do not need a dynamic solution, I would like to draw a static image.

I would be interested to hear about any alternative ideas. For example, since an arc is a pretty uniform object, I would guess, removing every other point from the data array would not result in a huge quality loss and would reduce the size of the SVG file to approximately half. I guess this can be done in the updateDataArray method, but I am not quite sure how.

Comment: This is a little bit surprising, since arcs are realized as Bezier curves and consist of at most 4 Bezier segments, i.e. 13 data points. How many arcs are in your construction? A more suitable way to try to reduce the size of the SVG file is to reduce the precision of the pixel coordinates defining the Bezier curves. If they are represented as floating point numbers with 16 digits this would be overkill. Can you make parts of such an SVG file available?

Comment: I am using a local copy of JSXgraph with some extensions, and probably these extensions cause a different way of saving the arc. In my SVG files the arcs are saved as curves with a lot of points along the way. Seeing the method updateDataArray on the JSXgraph arc reference page made me think that arcs are saved as any other curve using a dense set of points along the arc, but I see that it is not the case. Thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: What version of JSXGraph do you use?